# As an authorized user on a site with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, cookies

have a site on wordpress. 
in short: I need to authenticate the user to the site without using a function in wordpress.

user authorization did so:

```
$time = time() + 2 * 86400000;
$data = 'adminjdwD|'.$time;
$key = '$l*gvjdCkIUb;.Sj<code>=tpvo)myKm%lBH{<e?b3_%$l2EQWO2z/iUKc|&fBO|</code>mQ>E';
$salt = 'S[Rr@?Wa7k]qmDboI9e?K<code>mdRPg+1!w?&U)DeVf-p^0h;oD6.X+XBdYgF4^L:Y</code>C';
$key = hash_hmac('md5', $data, $key.$salt);
$hash = hash_hmac('md5', 'admin|'.$time, $key);
$cookie = 'admin|'.$time.'|'.$hash;
setcookie('wordpress_logged_in_'.md5('http://wp.ru'),$cookie,$time,'/','.wp.ru');
```

User authorizes no problems, but if the user is an administrator, the control panel will not let me. 
which cookies to register that would authorize the Administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a separate cookie for the /wp-admin pages.

I'm not sure how the admin cookie is constructed, but this should get you in the right direction.

try:

```
setcookie('wordpress_'.md5('http://wp.ru'),$adminCookie,$time,'/wp-admin','.wp.ru');
```